# How can I download an iOS app archive on macOS Catalina?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, catalina

With iTunes on versions of macOS before Catalina, it was possible to manage the apps on an iOS device and look at the `.ipa` files for them in Finder. But in the device management in Finder that used to be in iTunes, there is no Apps tab. Is there a way to get ahold of the `.ipa` app bundles now in Catalina?